# Scroll Div issue in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, scroll

Hi i'm developing a cordova application for android and sometimes I have a scroll issue on a div with a table. The scroll has a strange logarithm movement. Someone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I think I got the same problem. "Logarithmic" means I am scrolling to 1/4 of the page, but the scrollbar is already at the bottom. When I keep on scrolling the scrollbar just disappears below the bottom. Something with the height calculation seems to be wrong. On Chrome it works. But Android not (enabled via  appView.getView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);). Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ok. I think I found the "issue". I was experimenting with the scroll (aka appView.getView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);) on the emulator. And in the emulator I got this really weird scrolling behaviour. I switched to a real device and everything is fine now. And I guess that was also @Marco's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific on how the "logarithm moviment" should be? I faced some problems with scrolls and tables in two different situations and I hope the following information can help you.

**1 - Table out of devices width:** Sometimes, when you build a table, some incompatible CSS should make it wider than main div width and generate a strange horizontal scroll. Try to review your involved CSS;

**2 - Android Manifest:** I noted that some devices (especially those running older versions of Android) may have some performance issues caused by a Manifest Configuration. Try to change "hardwareAccelerated" to FALSE

```
 <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```

Hope it helps! Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused by the Android emulator. Check out if that weird scrolling is also present on a real device. It should not.

In my case I used the emulator for the Nexus 5x and got that strange "logarithmic" scrolling. When running my the very same app on a real Nexus 5x everything is fine.